# Infinity vs NAN values

Tags: c++, floating-point

I noticed a difference in the floating point values represented for Infinity and NAN. Is this specified some where in the standard?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <stdint.h>

union Double
{
    double value;
    uint64_t repr;
};

int main()
{
    Double d;
    d.value = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    std::cout << std::hex << "inf: " << d.repr << std::endl;

    d.value = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    std::cout << std::hex << "NAN: " << d.repr << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
Ouput: 
inf: 0x7ff0000000000000
NAN: 0x7ff8000000000000
```

Comment: The standard doesn't say anything about the representation of floating point numbers; that's an implementation detail.

Comment: First, your code has undefined behavior.  Second, why should infinity and not-a-number be the same thing?

Comment: If your implementation uses IEEE754 (and 99% it is), then it's described in IEEE754 standard. [Wikipedia on IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Comment: It's not specified in the C++ standard.   But, assuming your implementation supports IEEE floating point, the representation is specified in IEEE-754 (the IEEE technical standard for floating point).   And, with floating point representations that support them, NaN and infinities are distinct things, so have different representations.

Comment: If there is no upper limit defined in the standard some where then its implementation specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I noticed a difference in the floating point values represented for Infinity and NAN.

Yes, this is not surprising. These values differ, so their representation should differ too.

> Is this specified some where in the standard?

In the C++ standard? No.

In some floating-point standard, like IEEE-754? Yes.

Note: in C++, your union trick has undefined behavior. Use `memcpy` instead.

Comment: Can you elaborate on undefined behavior with union?

Comment: @PVRT: there are a ton of questions about it, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior

Comment: Indeed; copy the bytes instead.